# AWS, what happens when your ec2 (ecs) instance go over memory limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm not talking about memory requirement for `task`.

When an instance has 2gig memory, if more and more users keep connecting to it, memory usuage goes up and can overrun the server.

How can I avoid the crash?

Setting a right `soft/hard` memory limit (in ECS) can help here?

Comment: Yes, you can set hard limits on ram for tasks.

Comment: so should setting maximum (2gig hard limit) on instance with 2gig physical memory would be my best bet?

Comment: No, you need less. Regular OS on the instance and docker also need some memory. Maybe 1.5GB would be enough for ecs?

Comment: so If I set 1g, my task can use upto 1g, if I set 1.5g, my task can use upto 1.5g and somewhere near would be my best bet after leaving some amount of memory for OS ?

Comment: yes. [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/allocate-ecs-memory-tasks/) they explain how to set hard limit.

Comment: For the longer story (which includes Fargate) you can see here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/how-amazon-ecs-manages-cpu-and-memory-resources/